# iFrame postMessage and addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, postmessage

After reading multiple SO posts, I understand the best (or only) way to use javascript on an iFrame is by `postMessage` and `addEventListener`.  All of the sample code I've found online show something like this:

```
<div id="magazine-container">
    <iframe id="iFrame" height="500" width="700" src="https://issuu.com/lideres_mexicanos/docs/351grupoaries-issuu/76"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        let testString = 'MESSAGE FROM LOCALHOST';
        let frame = document.getElementById('iFrame');
        frame.contentWindow.postMessage(testString, '*');

        window.addEventListener('message', event => {
            console.log(event.data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Looking in the console, `event.data` does not contain variable `testString`.
Instead it contains this:

```
{"PrivacyManagerAPI":{"timestamp":1584457115641,"action":"getConsent","self":"quantserve.com","domain":"issuu.com","authority":"truste.com","type":"advertising"}}
```

I just can't figure out what's going on here.

**Edit**

I understand now that I wasn't attaching the `addEventListener` to the iFrame, but to the parent.  Is there a way to add the listener to the actual iFrame without having access to the source code to the page used in the iFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're calling `postMessage` on the **frame's contentWindow** you are sending a message to the iFrame, as I believe you intend.

However, you are adding an event listener to the parent window (aka `window`), *NOT* the iframe's content window. The message that you are `console.log`ing is not the one you sent, it is instead a different message that is being *received* by your page. This is likely either a response to the message you sent, or a message sent by a plugin you have installed on your browser.

To achieve the functionality of a parent communicating with a child iFrame, you must have access to the source code of the iframe so you can attach the event handler there, or be using a target with a defined API already set up.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So, is there no way to console log from within the iFrame if I don't have access to the source code?

Comment: Correct. There is no way to do this. This is because, if you could, you would be able to access potentially sensitive information. Imagine having a (hidden) iFrame to facebook.com, and then making that facebook.com access all of the users's private information and sending it back to the parent website! 
This is why the PostMessage mechanism is there, so pages only give out information they explicitly want to 

Note, that if you have an iFrame to a page which has the *same host* as the parent, you actually have full access, and do not need to rely on the postMessage

Comment: Right, that makes sense.  I had that in the back of my mind the whole time.  Thinking, this probably isn't possible and shouldn't be.  lol   Thanks again!  Awarded correct answer.